# What might be the equillibrium Distribution Function of Dark Matter?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, dark-matter

Can we assign a thermal distribution function to Dark Matter(not necessarily known ones)?

Is it possible that they won't even follow thermal distribution function and maybe a function of something else? Like just energy or amount of matter around but not its temperature.

All this is assuming thatI can assign a temperature which would need them to interact atleast weakly(like neutrinos).